# How to explain "x = (a = 3, b = ++a)" in c++?

Tags: c++

There are complete codes. And the output always is "4 4 4".

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    int x = (a = 3, b = ++a);
    std::cout << a << ' ' << b << ' ' << x << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would explain it as code you should never write.

Comment: Operations have order, you can look for it in any textbook or tutorial. Following this order, the first operation executed in `a = 3`, then `++a` makes `a` equals to 4, then `b` is assigned to the new value of `a` (that is 4), then `x` is assigned to the new value of `b` that is 4

Comment: This line `int x = (a = 3, b = ++a);` is equivalent to `a = 3; b = ++a; int x = b;` so the 4 4 4 output is what you would expect.

Comment: I guess you are thinking that `++a` should happen first. That is incorrect, `a = 3` happens first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression `(a = 3, b = ++a)` is evaluated from left to right and the value is `b = ++a` which itself has the value `b`. That is assigned to `x`. In other words  `x` will be the same as `b`.

Furthermore the *expression separator operator* `,` is a *sequencing* point, meaning that `a = 3` completes prior to the evaluation of `b = ++a`.

`++a` is therefore 4, and that is assigned to `b`, explaining the output.